# How do I fix my iframe image that caused my website format to break?

Tags: html, css

fooling around with html/css. I inserted an iframe into my website but it ended up ruining the website design. Before i put the iframe, i had a background image that covered the whole page. After adding the iframe image, the background image became smaller and now doesnt cover the whole page. Now the page background is half the original background image and half the color I set it to. And my footer is now below the original background image .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Restaurant</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <img class="logo" src="images/logo-adare-restaurant.png" 
                                alt="adare restaurant logo">
        </header>
        <nav>
            <a href="#">HOME</a>
            <a href="#">MENU</a>
            <a href="#">ORDER ONLINE</a>
            <a href="#">GIFT VOUCHER</a>
            <a href="#">CATERING</a>
            <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
        </nav>
        <main>
            <h1> let's meat </h1>
            <p>We love sharing good food with great people. We bring over 30 years industry experience and passion to Adare. With a dishes that are carefully designed to bring you a truly satisfying Irish food experience that you are sure to remember.   
            </p>
            <a href="MAILTO:@GMAIL.COM" target="_blank"> MAKE RESERVATION</a>
        </main>
        <section>
            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d47526.885445701904!2d-8.82649311104587!3d52.53857175981847!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x485b460ddb875af7%3A0xdb34accde986ee58!2sThe%20Carriage%20House%20at%20Adare%20Manor!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1595304969203!5m2!1sen!2sus" width="1024" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe>"
        </section>
        <footer>
            <p> Main St, Blackabbey, Adare, Co. Limerick - Copyright 2017© </p>
        </footer>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background-color: #2F3035;
    background-image: url(images/background-adare-restaurant.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

.container {
    width: 1024px;
    margin: auto;
}

header {
    height: 118px;
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.301);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 0;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
main {
    height: 400px; 
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-right: 240px;
    padding-left: 240px;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

footer {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    color: white;
    padding: 50px 0;
    margin: 100px 0;
}

footer p {
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center; 
}

h1 {
    font-size: 84px;
}

p {
    font-size: 18px; 
}

a{
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif; 
}

iframe {
    
}
```

How can I properly insert or format the iframe so this doesn't happen? Or more specifically, how can I insert the iframe and still have my background image cover the whole page?

Comment: Try adding **allowtransparency="true"** To your iframe tag.

Comment: Didn't change anything sadly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `background-attachment: fixed;` to your css body tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Restaurant</title>
    <style>

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background-color: #2F3035;
    background-image: url("https://elegancedecor.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Restaurant-Lighting_Elegance-Decor.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
background-attachment: fixed;
}

.container {
    width: 1024px;
    margin: auto;
}

header {
    height: 118px;
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.301);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 0;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
main {
    height: 400px; 
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-right: 240px;
    padding-left: 240px;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

footer {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    color: white;
    padding: 50px 0;
    margin: 100px 0;
}

footer p {
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center; 
}

h1 {
    font-size: 84px;
}

p {
    font-size: 18px; 
}

a{
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif; 
}

iframe {
    position: relative;
}


    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <img class="logo" src="images/logo-adare-restaurant.png" 
                                alt="adare restaurant logo">
        </header>
        <nav>
            <a href="#">HOME</a>
            <a href="#">MENU</a>
            <a href="#">ORDER ONLINE</a>
            <a href="#">GIFT VOUCHER</a>
            <a href="#">CATERING</a>
            <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
        </nav>
        <main>
            <h1> let's meat </h1>
            <p>We love sharing good food with great people. We bring over 30 years industry experience and passion to Adare. With a dishes that are carefully designed to bring you a truly satisfying Irish food experience that you are sure to remember.   
            </p>
            <a href="MAILTO:CRISMANRIQUE02@GMAIL.COM" target="_blank"> MAKE RESERVATION</a>
        </main>
        <section>
            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d47526.885445701904!2d-8.82649311104587!3d52.53857175981847!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x485b460ddb875af7%3A0xdb34accde986ee58!2sThe%20Carriage%20House%20at%20Adare%20Manor!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1595304969203!5m2!1sen!2sus" width="1024" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe>"
        </section>
        <footer>
            <p> Main St, Blackabbey, Adare, Co. Limerick - Copyright 2017© </p>
        </footer>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```